# Show $(\alpha,\beta)^T$ is a point on a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let M be a collection of points $M=\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\2 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 2\\2 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}$.

The points on a circle with radius r and center in $(a,b)^T\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is described by the equation
$(X-a)^2+(Y-b)^2=r^2$

which is equivalent with the equation

$2aX+2bY+(r^2-a^2-b^2)=X^2+Y^2$

Now let $v=\begin{pmatrix} 2a\\2b \\r^2-a^2-b^2 \end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^3$

Show that $(\alpha,\beta)^T$ is a point on the circle described above if and only if

$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta & 1 \end{pmatrix}\cdot v=\alpha^2+\beta^2$.

---

$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta & 1 \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 2a\\2b \\r^2-a^2-b^2 \end{pmatrix}=2a\alpha+2b\beta+r^2-a^2-b^2$

$\implies -((\alpha-a)^2+(\beta-b)^2)+r^2+\alpha^2+\beta^2$

$\implies -r^2+(\alpha-a)^2+(\beta-b)^2=0$

$\implies $ $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta & 1 \end{pmatrix}\cdot v=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta & 1 \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 2a\\2a \\r^2-a^2-b^2 \end{pmatrix}=2a\alpha+2b\beta+r^2-a^2-b^2=\alpha^2+\beta^2$

So I believe I have managed to show it one way "=>", but I am stuck on the other way "<=" of the proof.

Comment: Hint: the dot product is the square of the norm

Comment: I've looked at it for a while now and I can't seem to get started on it.

Comment: @Javi Are you hinting me to see that $\alpha^2+\beta^2=\alpha\alpha+\beta\beta$ and then using the fact that  the dot product is the square of the norm we have $\alpha\cdot \alpha + \beta\cdot \beta=|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2$. And then use the Pythagorean Theorem for Inner Product Spaces which states something like $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=|\alpha+\beta|^2=\langle\alpha+\beta,\alpha+\beta\rangle$?